# Is there a way to see SVN revision numbers in Windows Explorer?

Tags: svn, windows-explorer

Is there a way you can add a column to the Details view of Windows Explorer that shows the subversion revision number of each file?

I'm on Vista and am using TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not in Vista; see [Vista problems](http://tortoisesvn.net/vistaproblems) page at TortoiseSVN:

> The Windows explorer in Vista has
>   changed quite a bit, and one of those
>   changes was to abandon the additional
>   columns but introduce a new "property
>   system". Since the property system is
>   file type based, we can't add a column
>   for Subversion information anymore :(

It's doable in XP; see [TortoiseSVN doc](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-wcstatus.html#id442566):

> Simply right click on one of the
>   headings of a column, choose `More...`
>   from the context menu displayed. A
>   dialog will appear where you can
>   specify the columns and their order,
>   which is displayed in the “Detailed
>   View”. Scroll down until the entries
>   starting with SVN come into view.
>   Check the ones you would like to have
>   displayed and close the dialog by
>   pressing OK. The columns will be
>   appended to the right of those
>   currently displayed. You can reorder
>   them by drag and drop, or resize them,
>   so that they fit your needs.

Answer (score 3):

Prior to (and including) XP, you can find "SVN Revision" in the detail view of explorer if you have TortoiseSVN installed (remember to reboot). Enable it and then it should work.

After Vista, you can't do that.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that there is now a solution for this although I haven't tried it out myself.

[xplorer²](http://www.zabkat.com/blog/07Feb10-column-handlers-revived.htm)

Comment: It's basically an alternative Explorer - and I'm not fond of having parallel tools for everything - but at least now I can quickly check revision numbers. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In a subversion directory open windows explorer and right click on the column headers Choose More.. from the menu and then select the SVN attributes you want from the dialog .